# Visual studio code doesn't import opencv library into python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I was trying to write a python file that opens the camera,only that when I write `import cv2` it gives me an error

[image]

Comment: Did you install opencv using pip install opencv-python command?

Comment: Yes in the cmd and in the shell

Comment: Thank you for your question. In the future, please include code as formatted code, so that other users may copy and run the code themselves in order to help you. Please also clean up your code before posting (e.g. remove superfluous comments). In addition, it would be very helpful if you actually included the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import cv2
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = vc.read()
   cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

vc.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If this does not work, can you specify your error?

Comment: The error is in import cv2

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. The error that it gives me is this "Import "cv2" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)"

Comment: Maybe try connecting the right Python interpreter? This should resolve the error you are seeing since this will make the linter see which packages you have installed.